# What value does the spotify api accept in the "state" parameter when making authorisation requests?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, spotify

I understand that adding state is crucial for preventing things like cross-site request forgery, according to [Spotify Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow), but I can't find anything that says what to actually put in the parameter.

This is what my code looks like:

```
    def Authorise(self):
        params = {
            "client_id": self._CLIENT_ID,
            "scope": self.SCOPE,
            "redirect_uri": "https://open.spotify.com",
            "state": 
        }
        self.mostRecentResponse = requests.get(self.AUTH_URL, params=params,verify=False)
        self.mostRecentResponseJson = self.mostRecentResponse.json()
```

without state, it works but warns me that it is dangerous. Also the json always fails to work, even though the status code is 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state code is any value you want it to be. It acts as a unique identifier for you to validate the response by providing your own unique key. For instance you could make this a hash code of some value unique to your session, some random string, etc. It's any value you want to pass. Proceeding without it, is it dangerous? Well that's debatable but it's an extra layer of confidence in security.

Comment: So it's essentially a password?

Comment: In a sense it is. It can be used creatively to store information as well but it's certainly not required because you do have an API key or credentials already.